# Read and check Excel file

Tags: php, excel

I am new in PHP and ZEND. I read excel file and check values before insert them to database.

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {//MM
                $items = array();
                for ($col = 1; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
                    $cell = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                    $items[] = $cell->getValue();
                    $items[]=trim($items[]);
                    if ($col = 2)                       { continue;
                    }else{
                        $items[]=preg_replace("/^[-\s]$/", "", $items);// or abs($items[]);
                        if(!is_numeric ($items)){
                         $items[]=null;                  
                    }
                    }
                }
                $rating = mysql_escape_string($items[0]);

        and so on...
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\httpd-2.2.21\htdocs\project\zend\application\modules\admin\models\bankranking\BankRankAdmin.php on line 204
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$items[] = $cell->getValue();
$items[]=trim($items[]);
```

Try out with this

```
$items[] = trim($cell->getValue());
```

Remove the following line

```
$items[]=trim($items[]);
```

Comment: I already tried and have another error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\httpd-2.2.21\htdocs\project\zend\application\modules\admin\model‌​s\bankranking\BankRankAdmin.php on line 204

Answer (score 0):

```
$item = $cell->getValue();

                    $item = trim($item);
                    if ($col != 2) {
                        $item = str_replace(array('-', ' '), "", $item);
                        if (!is_numeric($item)) {
                            $item = NULL;
                        }
                    }
                    $items[] = $item;
```